# To optimize 20 parameters which should be the best algorithm to use?

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, genetic-algorithm, hyperopt

I have 20 parameters that can take binary value which are passed to function to return the score like this.

```
score = fmin( para 1, para 2 , para 3,.....para20)
```

Now to optimize this scenario, which can be the best algorithm ?

I read about genetic algorithm where in chromosome can do mutation and crossover to select best combination out of 2^20 search points.

I also read about hyperopt that optimises the function but in less number of trials.

Which can be the better one ? Any pros or cons of using these algorithms ?

Comment: How long does it take to evaluate one possible combination? 2^20 isn't that big (around 1 million) and if the evaluation can be done efficiently, you can simply bruteforce to find the best solution.

Comment: Not sure how you'd find the "best" without iterating the entire search space, or at least narrowing down which set of parameters really gives the best improvements

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the properties you expect your function to have.  If you have reason to believe that similar parameter sets have similar scores, then you can try [simulated annealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) or [genetic algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm).

However, if you don't have reason to expect similar parameters will generate similar scores, those methods won't help:  you would do just as well picking parameter sets at random.  But (as mentioned in the comments), 2^20 isn't much more than a million trials:  if your function isn't too expensive, you could just try them all.